# Sitecore multisite : How to configure SSL for different domain

Tags: iis, ssl, sitecore, sitecore7

We have a multi-site implementation with different domain names.

e.g. mydomainA.com.au, subdomain.mydomainB.com.au, mydomainC.com.au

All these sites are hosted under one sitecore instance. We need to enable the SSL for each domain names for which we have wild card SSL Certificates each.

We are using IIS 8.

Could some one suggest what's the best way to configure multiple SSLs for single sitecore multisite instance?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is depend on the wishes and requirements.

The simple solution in IIS 8 there are new options it should be possible to assign multiple Certificates to one website. Add some flexibility and use for each domain a separate, dedicated IP (also needed for older IIS)

More advanced reduce dependency On the CD create for each site a own website with own webroot in IIS (on the same server) (Sitecore licenses need for each IIS site) and use the same Sitecore databases. It give you a IIS and Sitecore log file for eache site and multiple webroots to maintain. See [Multiple IIS Sites](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Multiple%20IIS%20Sites.aspx)

For Sitecore CD there is no special ssl config needed.

Comment: not sure what you meant wishes and requirements. It's pretty clear that it's a multi site implementation where sites have different domain names and needs to support multiple certificates.

Comment: Do you want to isolate a site and have a seperated application pool for each site?